# How to get the result of job while it's running from controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, task-queue

I'm trying to perform a asynchronous task that fills an array of object from a `REST` web service call.

I'm writing the code inside the `handle()` method inside the `job`'s class.

The controller should be able to retrieve an `object` from that `array` at any time.

This task is supposed to run **continuously** so that whenever I want to retrieve an `object`, my `array` still contains data.

My question is how to make a `job` that executes permanently and how can I retrieve the data from my controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google "php laravel daemon"

Answer (score 0):

You need to store (cache) array from job somewhere (db, redis, files) after every operation.

Then retrieve "fresh" array in controller from storage.

If objects in array are similar, you can create model and use standard laravel capabilities.

To run permanent task you can use this console command:

```
nohup php artisan {command_name} &
```